# Child router in custom element

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to add a router to a custom element. The element should have two subviews where user can switch between them. However, I have run into a problem:

```
export class customElement {
   configureRouter(config,router) { ... } //this is not getting called
}
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749117/aurelia-how-do-i-use-a-child-router-and-dynamics-child-routes) is related and an answer to the question states that "It will not work if it is a custom element."

Is there a workaround or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. Custom elements are not the same as routed view-models. And Aurelia offers no way you can easily achieve this with a custom element.